# C - not entering if even when he should

Tags: c, if-statement, char, compare

I'm seriously mad right now. I need to compare one string with second, when chars from second string can somehow create first string. Example

---

foo1 = bill

foo2 = boril

*foo2 can create foo1, because it contains all the letters from foo1.*

---

So there's my program:

secret = religion

lettersGuessed = religonvpst

```
for(i = 0; i < lenSecret; i++){  
    for(l = 0; l < lenGuessed; l++)
        printf("A: %c, B: %c, C: %d\n", secret[i], lettersGuessed[l], count);
        if(secret[i] == lettersGuessed[l]){
            printf("HI\n");
            count++;
            break;
        }
        printf("C: %d\n", count);
}
```

But variable **count** always stays at 0. This is output from console:

http://pastebin.com/YrHiNLNi

As you can see right from beginning, when **secret[i] == lettersGuessed[l]** in **if** should return true(1), it returns false(0). What's wrong with this? Why it's not working?

Comment: try using [`strcmp`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strcmp/) to compare strings.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but note that it's generally frowned upon to use "l" as variable name, since depending on font it can be easily confused with an I (upper-case i).

Comment: Also, you should almost never use the identifiers defau1t and defauIt as labels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you don't have curly braces after your second for loop. If you don't wrap the block of code you want to iterate over with curly braces, only the code before the first semi-colon encountered will be executed. In this case, your second loop will iterate over the printf statement but nothing else. So variable l will always be equal to lenGuessed when the if statement is executed and no letter from the first word matches the last letter of the second word, therefore count is never incremented.

Comment: Original one (for(i = 0; i < lenSecret; i++)  
  for(l = 0; l < lenGuessed; l++)
   if(secret[i] == lettersGuessed[l]){
    count++;
    break;
   }) not working though, this version is edited one.

Comment: Try adding curly braces for both forloops

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is totaly crazy.

Code that I posted in my question was of course wrong, because I forget braces of second for loop. Small, but fatal mistake, I know, but I was seriously mad so I didn't pay attention. Anyway, the original code is following:

```
int isWordGuessed(char secret[], char lettersGuessed[]){
    int i, l, count = 0;
    int lenSecret = strlen(secret);
    int lenGuessed = strlen(lettersGuessed);

    for(i = 0; i < lenSecret; i++)  
        for(l = 0; l < lenGuessed; l++)
            if(secret[i] == lettersGuessed[l]){
                count++;
                break;
        }

return lenSecret == count ? 1 : 0;

}
```

At first, it was returning 0. After compiling it with different tools and launching it on two different OS (Windows 7 64-bit and Windows XP 32-bit) i was finaly able to get 1 from that function.

It seems like variable **count** had non-zero value while launching, so instead of **int i, l, count;** I wrote int **i, l, count = 0;**

Well, now I don't understand only one thing - why sometimes variables has non-zero value even when I never touched them. It happened to my before, but only in C, in other languages I never had such a problem.

Comment: If you don't initialize a variable, its value is not known. There are exceptions (I believe C99 requires all variables declared `static` to initialize to `0`), but generally the initial value can be anything, and will likely just be junk left behind on the stack.

Comment: If you have a second question, please post a second question. Don't post an answer that asks a question, that is just confusing and is likely to be deleted.